# Is Server-Side-Rendering with Spring Boot backend and React.JS front end possible?

Tags: seo, google, web-development, java, react-js

I am making a web application that utilizes java & spring boot for the back-end and react.js for the front-end. I have been doing research more recently on SEO performance on client-side-rendering and it seems like it affects SEO and performance so I wanted to know if server-side-rendering is possible with this?

All the articles I seem to come across say that SSR is only available with a node.js back-end and have seen .NET but nothing for spring boot.